# Subsetting of rows in R data frame

Tags: r

I am currently scraping some data from the web and an example of the data looks like this:

```
    col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d
    1     | 2     | 44    | home1
    1     | 3     | 44    | home1
    1     | 7     | 44    | home1
    1     | 5     | 44    | home1
    1     | 2     | 44    | home1
    1     | 3     | 44    | home1
    1     | 7     | 44    | home1
    1     | 5     | 44    | home1
    2     | 8     | 42    | home1
    2     | 6     | 42    | home1
    2     | 4     | 42    | home1
    2     | 1     | 42    | home1
```

As seen in the example above, there are a total of 12 rows. The correct data is supposed to only have 8 rows of data, using "col_a" as reference, each unique "col_a" is supposed to have only 4 rows. So in this case row 5 to 8 are duplicates of row 1 to 4. That being said, the data scraped has 100,000 over rows and such duplicates happen all over the place. Is there a way to keep just the first 4 rows of each unique "col_a"? I cant think of an efficient way other than looping through each row.

Comment: Using `dplyr`, `df %>%
  group_by(col_a) %>%
  slice(1:4)
`

Comment: this works perfectly rather than looping thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a dupe for this but since I can't find one I'll write up an answer.

Using `dplyr`, we could do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(col_a) %>% slice(1:4)

#  col_a col_b col_c col_d
#  <int> <int> <int> <fct>
#1     1     2    44 home1
#2     1     3    44 home1
#3     1     7    44 home1
#4     1     5    44 home1
#5     2     8    42 home1
#6     2     6    42 home1
#7     2     4    42 home1
#8     2     1    42 home1
```

---

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[1:4], by = col_a]
```

and base R.

```
df[with(df, ave(col_b, col_a, FUN = seq_along) <= 4), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the different values in col_a with:

```
col_a_unique <- unique(data$col_a)
```

Then eventually loop over it and keep only the first four of each:

```
for (a in col_a_unique)
{
 to_keep=data[which(data$col_a==a),][1:4]
}
```

`wihch()` will select only the lines fulfilling the equality, i.e. all the elements correcponding to a given value on col_a, and then with `[1:4]` you select the first four elements.

Then you need to create an appropriate object to store `to_keep` at each loop step.

This is a detailed way, there are more concise way of doing it.

Comment: Ronak Shah's slice method from dplyr works perfectly without looping. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Base `R` with the help of `data.table`'s `rowid()`:

```
df[data.table::rowid(df$col_a) < 5, ]

#    col_a col_b col_c col_d
# 1      1     2    44 home1
# 2      1     3    44 home1
# 3      1     7    44 home1
# 4      1     5    44 home1
# 9      2     8    42 home1
# 10     2     6    42 home1
# 11     2     4    42 home1
# 12     2     1    42 home1
```